# azure advisor sdk not giving security recommendations

Tags: azure, azure-python-sdk, azure-advisor

I am using the azure advisor python SDK to fetch advisor recommendations. It is giving me all the recommendations other than 'security'.

When I first used the same code, it used to give me 'security' recommendation as well,  but all of a sudden it stopped giving me 'security' recommendations.

From Azure portal: I can see a total of 33 recommendations (30 are security, and remaining are 1 of each -operationalExcellence, Reliability, performance). But when I run the code, I get only 3 recommendations, other than 'security'. Can some one please help me, if any default configurations has to be changed?

[image]

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.costmanagement import CostManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.advisor import AdvisorManagementClient
import sys
import os

SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx"

client = CostManagementClient(credential=DefaultAzureCredential())  # noqa: F841
print(client)

advisor_client = AdvisorManagementClient(
        credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
        subscription_id=SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    )
print(advisor_client)

def call(response, *args, **kwargs):
        return response.http_response
print(call)

response = advisor_client.recommendations.generate(cls=call)  # noqa: F841
print(response)
cached_list = advisor_client.recommendations.list()
for data in cached_list:
    print(data)
```

I have tried the Azure REST API for Advisor as well, it is also giving all recommendations BUT skipping 'security' category.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using the azure advisor python SDK to fetch advisor recommendations. It is giving me all the recommendations other than 'security'

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

You can use the below code to get the all categories of all advisor recommendations with count.

**Code:**

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.costmanagement import CostManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.advisor import AdvisorManagementClient

SUBSCRIPTION_ID = ""

client = CostManagementClient(credential=DefaultAzureCredential())
advisor_client = AdvisorManagementClient(
        credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
        subscription_id=SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    )
category_count = {}
response = advisor_client.recommendations.list()
for data in response:
    category = data.category
    if category in category_count:
        category_count[category] += 1
    else:
        category_count[category] = 1

for category, count in category_count.items():
         print(f"{category}: {count}")
```

**Output:**

```
Cost: xx
HighAvailability: xx
Security: xx
Performance: xx
OperationalExcellence: xxx
```

[image]

You can check the particular to list the advisor recommendation. For example, I have taken here **`performance`** to check the impacted_fields with the below code.

**Code:**

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.costmanagement import CostManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.advisor import AdvisorManagementClient

SUBSCRIPTION_ID = ""

client = CostManagementClient(credential=DefaultAzureCredential())
advisor_client = AdvisorManagementClient(
        credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),
        subscription_id=SUBSCRIPTION_ID
    )
category_count = {}
response = advisor_client.recommendations.list(filter="Category eq 'Performance'")
for data in response:
    print(data.impacted_field)
```

**Output:**

```
Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines
Microsoft.Kusto/Clusters
Microsoft.Kusto/Clusters
Microsoft.Kusto/Clusters
MICROSOFT.SQL/SERVERS/DATABASES
MICROSOFT.SQL/SERVERS/DATABASES
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Recommendations - List - REST API (Azure Advisor) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/advisor/recommendations/list?tabs=HTTP)